# Device URI for Printer

Tags: centos, usb, printer

I have the system printer GUI installed on Centos 6.6. I added the printer (HP LaserJet Pro P1102). The model exists. The problem is that the GUI is asking for the Device URI which I'm not sure where to get it from.

[image]

The printer is connected through the USB device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally use this approach when plugging in a USB based printer.

1. Unplug the USB printer cable from your computer and enter this command:

   ```
   $ tail -f /var/log/syslog
   ```
2. Reconnect the USB printer cable, you should see some messages appearing.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to stop the logging.
4. Check whether the printer gets correctly detected by the USB subsystem and determine its USB vendor/product IDs and the USB bus and device addresses:

   ```
   $ lsusb
   ```
5. Note: The USB bus and device addresses change if you turn off or unplug the printer. Please re-run this command if needed.

**NOTE:** You can also attempt to use the command line tool `hp-info -i`.

#### References

- [Debugging Printing Problems - Ubuntu Official docs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems)